# How to get group by primaryGroupId ? How to convert primaryGroupId to dn?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I can read user `primaryGroupId`:
[image]
val entry = ldapConnectionPool.getEntry(userDn)
primaryGroupID = entry.getAttributeValue(PRIMARY_GROUP_ID.ldapFieldName)

it is a string which contains number. In my case it is always `513`

As I understand user must have this group and it is setup during creation.

I want to get group **DN** based on **primaryGroupId**

I've tried to get primary group from group entry:

```
ldapConnectionPool.getEntry(groupDn)
val token = entry.getAttributeValue("PrimaryGroupToken")
```

But it always null

Another option I've found is suffix of objectSid:

[image]

But solutions from here don't work for me:

[How to convert the SID to String and vice versa in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118290/how-to-convert-the-sid-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-java)

If I use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21818633/2674303

I get wrong suffix.

[image]
[image]

Any ideas hwo to fix it ?

**Update.**

Based on answer user1686 I was able to understand that query like this works properly:

```
ldapConnectionPool.searchForEntry(baseDn, SearchScope.SUB, "objectSid=S-1-5-32-550")
```

But prefix (in my case `"S-1-5-32"`) depends on folder.

**1.**
[image]
**2.**
[image]

And unfortunately query with wikd card return null:

```
ldapConnectionPool.searchForEntry(baseDn, SearchScope.SUB, "*-550")
```

Comment: Where did `PrimaryGroupToken` come from?

Comment: @user1686 not sure if I understood you correctly.  It is calculated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygrouptoken

Answer (score 0):

`primaryGroupId` is a RID (the last component of a SID). You need to suffix it to the *domain* SID in order to get the correct group SID.

1. Read the `objectSid` attribute from the domain's root entry (`dc=foo,dc=bar`).
2. Convert that to a string.
3. Concatenate domain objectSid + `"-"` + user primaryGroupID, to obtain the group SID.

Although objectSid *stores* the SID in binary form, AD DC actually has a custom matching rule that allows you to *search* for a string SID.

4. Search the directory for `(objectSid=` + the group SID + `)`.
5. Use the DN of the entry you found.

Comment: Let me share my experience.
1. How to convert objectSid binary to string
```
val domainSidBytes = entry.getAttributeValueBytes("objectSid")
val domainSidString = LdapUtils.convertBinarySidToString(domainSidBytes)
```
2. Yes this quesry works properly:
```
ldapConnectionPool.searchForEntry(baseDn, SearchScope.SUB, "objectSid=S-1-5-32-550")
```

The problem here that all my groups have different prefixes

Comment: you can take a look here for more details: https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk/issues/151

Comment: Also. please read topic update

Comment: The primary group always has the domain SID as its base, that's how primaryGroupId is defined. The groups that have a `S-1-5-32-` SID prefix are a distraction – they only apply to domain controllers themselves (i.e. they're basically the "local groups" of DCs) and cannot _be set_ as a user's "primary" group – so they can be ignored for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Looks like the common rule is working here:

http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2023/08/22/0005/3037/338909/09/0917048cbe.jpg

It takes sid of closest parent entry which has objectSid. Isn't it ?

Comment: How can I filter groups which could be set as user primary group ?

Comment: No, that's not how SIDs work.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what question have you answered -  there are 2 questions

Comment: Looks like you are right.
I just tried to change user primaryGroupId. And when I tried to change to group whose objectSid started from `S-1-5-32` - I've got an ldap error although I was able to add user to that group via member field. Where I can read about it ?